# What is the prefered way of simulating ui-sref from ng-swipe event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

**State Change On swipe:**
*I need to trigger a state change using a swipe event.  The ui-router docs lead em to `$state.go()` but i'm not sure if this is the best method?*

### **QUESTION:**

**Using `ng-swipe` events how do I trigger a `$state.go()` with params?? Or is there a better approach to this scenario?**

I have a state called:

```
name: 'root.store.ad.page.pageNumber', 'url': '/:pageNumber'
```

on swipe of an `li` ideally it would look like this(doesn't have to):

```
 <li ng-swipe-left="root.store.ad.page.pageNumber({pageNumber: nextPage})"></li>
```

Currently it looks like this :

```
<li ng-swipe-right="setPage(page.pageindex)"></li>
```

I've tried [$state.go()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) but i'm having trouble making it work with params?

**ERROR:**
[image]

**CTRL:**

```
scope.setPage = function(val){


      //trying to make it just jump to page 5.
      $state.go('root.store.ad.page.pageNumber',
          {
            pageNumber: 5,
          }
        );


    };
```

Comment: You are getting undefined on something, did you check to make sure that your `setPage(page.pageindex)` was passing a valid number through to the `setPage` function?

Comment: I put a hard string/number into the seepage function  to see if that was the case.   Example above

Comment: If you debug it, is $state set? Are you injecting it? You should be able to call $state.go("your.path", { param1: "value", param2: "value2"});... Are you able to route to it manually? I did notice its set as `url: "/:pagenumber"` and not `url: "/{pagenumber}". According to their page it should be the same but it works for us when we use the `{}`. I would put a debug point right above the $state.go call and see what your variables are set to

Comment: @John it was totally the {}.  if you wanna put the answer down i'll mark it correct.

Comment: Awesome great to hear :), added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Comments, changing it from

```
name: 'root.store.ad.page.pageNumber', 'url': '/:pageNumber'
```

to

```
name: 'root.store.ad.page.pageNumber', 'url': '/{pageNumber}'
```

worked